# Spring + hibernate Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

First and foremost: I'm a total n00b at this and am really trying to understand this, but these particular exceptions don't help me too much. So maybe I just need a pointer to appropriate documentation or maybe not, but this is killing me now for a couple of days and I'm no closer to anything resembling a solution.

I got a sample project which declared one DB table. That project also exposed this table via REST. The project is broken down into 4 modules:

- config: contains various configuration items, such as hibernate configuration, etc. All configuration is in .java files, not .xml
- model: contains DB model declarations / entities (also .java annotated)
- data: contains DAOs and their implementations for each model (one so far). Contains AbstractDao (simple sessionFactory wrapper / persistence implementor), UserDao (interface for rest methods) and UserDaoImpl (implementation for users model)
- web: controllers publishing DAOs to REST via `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity`

The app publishes to tomcat 8 and works as expected.

Now I tried to add another model into the app, so I added a new .java to models subdirectory containing another annotated model / entity.

Immediately when I do that, my app won't start any more.

I get exception Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory sima.data.AbstractDao.sessionFactory;
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in sima.config.HibernateConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed;
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to open JDBC connection for schema management target
java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
```

please note that this exception is for the existing object which I haven't modified. I added a new object into models/ subdirectory and the entire world exploded around me.

Then I tried to add the DAOs and Controller as well, but it naturally didn't help. It would seem I'm forgetting something, but being a n00b and having had no explanation on the subject from the people giving me the sample I'm just stumped.

Can you help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your DataSource is closed because of an error happening in the background.** That error is likely caused by the new model definition you added to your project. Since you mentioned that you are using hibernate but not having too much experience with it yet, I believe what happened is that:

- you added a new model (referencing a table)
- the referenced table does not exist (or just not referenced correctly)
- schema validation failed when the application started up
- the underlying DB connection got closed

In order to resolve the problem I would suggest temporarily increasing the at least debug level (at this point you would surely see the reason behind the closed connection - the real error). You should probably consider switching on hibernate debug logging just to be sure.

Comment: Model works. :) I had a stupid typo: break instead of brake... Now it fails when I add the REST controller :( This is so much fun :p

Comment: Is there really no way of telling Hibernate to raise a fatal exception when DB model binding fails?