# How to debug Spring + hibernate Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This is a follow up of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365022/spring-hibernate-servlet-init-for-servlet-dispatcher-threw-exception).

My problem is that pretty much anything I do will cause this exception and my server not working. I've just caused this some 5 times already and EVERY time I was only able to find the problem either by chance or the change was such that I could revert.

For example: if I change hibernate parameter hbm2ddl.auto from update to validate, this will yield the error. However `hbm2ddl.auto=update` clearly states that there are no alter statements for my tables. I went through entire log several times and could not find the cause of malfunction.

There is nothing of note in the log: huge amount of DEBUG entries, a few INFOs and one WARN (the exception telling me nothing which disables the server). Darn: what the heck constitutes an ERROR for Hibernate programmers then?

I could paste the log somewhere and ask you guys to find my problem for me, but I'd feel so much better if I was able to find such problems myself.

Comment: Does the db account that your hibernate is using have all rights allowed?

Comment: Without any more information we're just probing in the dark here just like you. Just a few thoughts: 1) have you tried try-catching the creation of the SessionFactory and extensively logged the exception before rethrowing it? 2) have you tried creating a new empty database, then use hbm2ddl.auto=create, and see what the differences turn out to be between the new and old database schema?

Comment: To Dale: no, the DB user has NO rights, except SIUD on each object being mapped. @mlkammer: it's not the differences I want to catch. If it was that, I can continue staring at model declarations. What I want to achieve is the particular error that's causing the ruckus at any one time. The try-catching of SessionFactory suggestion seems to be a great suggestion, but I fear I will get the final "Session has closed" exception which is useless for debugging. I would much rather see a "Field xxx not found in DB schema" exception if this was the actual culprit.